# Не могу по нажатию кнопки выводить значение

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго всем дня, в приложении присутствует таблица с колонкой `Id` и к каждой колонке есть кнопка. Нужно по нажатию кнопки вводить в консоль значение `Id` 
написал скрипт который по нажатию выводит в консоль `id` строки. Но почему-то не работает.
Так я вывожу допустим значение `Id` 4-й строки:

```
var a = $('.inputik').eq(3).val();
console.log(a);
```

но мне надо `id` той колонки, где нажата кнопка. Cделал так, но не сработало:

```
var a = $('.inputik').eq(this).val();
console.log(a);
```

Вот моя примерная таблица надо по нажатию на кнопку ввдить значене из `Hidden input`

```
     <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th scope="col">ID</th>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Num</th>
    <th scope="col">Lat</th>
    <th scope="col">Lot</th>
    <th scope="col">Status</th>
    <th scope="col">Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="first">1</td>
    <td>Driver1</td>
    <td> 01</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td> 0</td>
    <td>offline</td>
    <td><button id="j_idt8:0:myButn" name="j_idt8:0:myButn" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only button" onclick="show();PrimeFaces.ab({s:'j_idt8:0:myButn',a:true});return false;" style="background: grey;" type="submit"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">CHeck</span></button><script id="j_idt8:0:myButn_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("CommandButton","widget_j_idt8_0_myButn",{id:"j_idt8:0:myButn",widgetVar:"widget_j_idt8_0_myButn"});</script>
<td><input class="inputik" type="hidden" value="Driver1" /></td>

</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="first"> 2 </td>
    <td> Driver2</td>
    <td>02</td>
    <td> 69.442771</td>
    <td> 45.536307</td>
    <td>offline </td>
    <td><button id="j_idt8:1:myButn" name="j_idt8:1:myButn" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only button" onclick="show();PrimeFaces.ab({s:'j_idt8:1:myButn',a:true});return false;" style="background: grey;" type="submit"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">CHeck</span></button><script id="j_idt8:1:myButn_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("CommandButton","widget_j_idt8_1_myButn",{id:"j_idt8:1:myButn",widgetVar:"widget_j_idt8_1_myButn"});</script>
     <td><input class="inputik" type="hidden" value="Driver2" />  </td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="first">3 </td>
    <td> Driver3</td>
    <td> 03</td>
    <td> 43.380050 </td>
    <td>50.30960</td>
    <td> offline</td>
    <td><button id="j_idt8:2:myButn" name="j_idt8:2:myButn" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only button" onclick="show();PrimeFaces.ab({s:'j_idt8:2:myButn',a:true});return false;" style="background: grey;" type="submit"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">CHeck</span></button><script id="j_idt8:2:myButn_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("CommandButton","widget_j_idt8_2_myButn",{id:"j_idt8:2:myButn",widgetVar:"widget_j_idt8_2_myButn"});</script>
    <td> <input class="inputik" type="hidden" value="Driver3" /></td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="first"> 4 </td>
    <td>Driver4</td>
    <td>04 </td>
    <td> 50.354619</td>
    <td> 50.078559</td>
    <td> Offline </td>
    <td><button id="j_idt8:3:myButn" name="j_idt8:3:myButn" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only button" onclick="show();PrimeFaces.ab({s:'j_idt8:3:myButn',a:true});return false;" style="background: grey;" type="submit"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">CHeck</span></button><script id="j_idt8:3:myButn_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("CommandButton","widget_j_idt8_3_myButn",{id:"j_idt8:3:myButn",widgetVar:"widget_j_idt8_3_myButn"});</script>
   <td><input class="inputik" type="hidden" value="Driver4" /> </td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="first">5 </td>
    <td>Driver5 </td>
    <td> 05</td>
    <td>  30.37569 </td>
    <td> 49.778018 </td>
    <td>Offline</td>
    <td><button id="j_idt8:4:myButn" name="j_idt8:4:myButn" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only button" onclick="show();PrimeFaces.ab({s:'j_idt8:4:myButn',a:true});return false;" style="background: grey;" type="submit"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">CHeck</span></button><script id="j_idt8:4:myButn_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("CommandButton","widget_j_idt8_4_myButn",{id:"j_idt8:4:myButn",widgetVar:"widget_j_idt8_4_myButn"});</script>
 <td> <input class="inputik" type="hidden" value="Driver5" /></td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="first">6</td>
    <td> Driver6</td>
    <td> 06</td>
    <td> 0 </td>
    <td>  0</td>
    <td> Offline  </td>
    <td><button id="j_idt8:5:myButn" name="j_idt8:5:myButn" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only button" onclick="show();PrimeFaces.ab({s:'j_idt8:5:myButn',a:true});return false;" style="background: grey;" type="submit"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">CHeck</span></button><script id="j_idt8:5:myButn_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("CommandButton","widget_j_idt8_5_myButn",{id:"j_idt8:5:myButn",widgetVar:"widget_j_idt8_5_myButn"});</script>
                   <td>
                   <input class="inputik" type="hidden" value="Driver6" />
                   </td></td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Куски кода какие-то обрывистые, можно код вместе с навешиванием обработчика события на кнопку

Comment: `eq` используется только для ID элемента. Покажите ваш код и вам помогут

Comment: По нажатию кнопки вводить в консоль значение? Эмм?

Comment: Параметр eq - это индекс в массиве выбранных по селектору элементов. https://api.jquery.com/eq/ Таким образом первоочередная задача - определить  определить номер строки, на которой щёлкнули свою кнопку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот версия с `eq`

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn').on('click', function(){
   console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).text());
  })
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>#1</td>
  <td>blah</td>
  <td>blah</td>
  <td><button class="btn">
  click!
  </button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>#2</td>
  <td>blah</td>
  <td>blah</td>
  <td><button class="btn">
  click!
  </button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>#3</td>
  <td>blah</td>
  <td>blah</td>
  <td><button class="btn">
  click!
  </button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Когда в 7 элементе кнопка

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>#1</td>
  <td>blah</td>
  <td>blah</td>
  <td>blah</td>
  <td>blah</td>
  <td><button class="ui-button">
  click!
  </button></td>
  <td><input class="inputik" type="hidden" value="Driver5" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>#2</td>
  <td>blah</td>
  <td>blah</td>
  <td>blah</td> 
  <td>blah</td>
  <td><button class="ui-button">
  click!
  </button></td>
  <td><input class="inputik" type="hidden" value="Driver6" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>#3</td>
  <td>blah</td>
  <td>blah</td>
  <td>blah</td>
  <td>blah</td>
  <td><button class="ui-button">
  click!
  </button></td>
  <td><input class="inputik" type="hidden" value="Driver7" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ui-button').on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(7).children().val());
  })
})
```

Comment: а если между тегами   <td><input class="inputik" type="hidden" value="Driver5" /> </td> как его значение получить ???

Comment: этот инпут в первом <td>?

Comment: нет в 5 теге находится

Comment: я добавил в ответ

Comment: не получается...Сомтри  я зименил свой код на свю таблицу

Comment: можеш свою таблицу загрузить в вопрос

Comment: Вадим загрузил ,перебпробов все методы .не один невывдит результат

Comment: я загрузил новый скрипт, в ответе последний под js, все работает

Comment: L.Vadim благожарю вас !

Comment: you welcome :))

Answer (score 2):

Вы неверно пытаетесь взять значение через val(), это подходит для тегов типа input, к примеру. С тегами типа td нужно брать их содержимое через html().

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
    id = $(this).parent().parent().find('td:first-child').html();
    console.log(id);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>#1</td>
      <td>blah</td>
      <td>blah</td>
      <td><button class="btn">
      click!
      </button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#2</td>
      <td>blah</td>
      <td>blah</td>
      <td><button class="btn">
      click!
      </button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#3</td>
      <td>blah</td>
      <td>blah</td>
      <td><button class="btn">
      click!
      </button></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Станислав Все ок именно это я и хочу

Comment: Но как обратться допустими не к 1 а -3 эелементу строки :?

Comment: id = $(this).parent().parent().find('td:first-child').html();

Comment: в этой строке для меня путаница не моглиб разьяснить

Comment: @elik, про строчку, давайте на куски ее разделим и разберем.

$(this) - это бы получили элемент, откуда происходит вызов нашего обработчика click, то есть мы получили тут кнопку; 
.parent() - это мы получили родителя кнопки, то есть тег td; 
.parent() - это мы получили родителя td, то есть тег tr; 
.find('td:first-child') - это мы нашли в теге tr его первый дочерний td элемент; 
.html() - это мы получили содержимое первого дочернего td в нашем tr.

Соответственно, если мы хотим получить не первый, а третий, или какой-либо еще, то мы используем в поиске не td:first-child, а что-то еще.

Comment: как я понел вы нали элемент по ('td:first-child'

Comment: но значит можно указать и eq для td

Comment: Извините, что не сразу написал комментарий, палец соскочил и отправил его раньше, чем дописал. В общем, смотрите мой комментарий выше, плюс вместо td:first-child да, вы можете использовать любой другой удобный вам css-селектор или их комбинацию, например - :nth-child. Ну или воспользоваться средствами JQuery и из всей найденной выборки дочерних элементов взять нужный с помощью функции eq(), вы правы.

Comment: @Cтанислав  Благодарю за такой полный ответ !

Comment: сделал при помощи eq все  получилось!

Comment: @elik здорово :) Правда лично я советовал бы брать нужную колонку не по ее номеру, так как их порядок может со временем поменяться и порушить ваш код, а либо как в предложенном варианте ниже, про data-атрибуты, либо присваивая колонке с номером некий класс (class='id', например) и ища потом эту колонку по нему. Но это в том случае, если код таблицы у вас генерируется автоматически, а не пишется каждый раз руками, во втором случае проще, конечно, не городить лишнего.

Comment: Да станслав Метод сергея более правльный.Но и вамс СпасибоЁ

Answer (score 1):

Хочу предложить такой новаторский вариянт:

```
<tr>
  <td>#3</td>
  <td>blah</td>
  <td>blah</td>
  <td><button class="btn" data-row-index="3">
      click!
  </button></td>
</tr>
```

Скрипт

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
   var id = $('.inputik').eq($(this).data('rowIndex')).val();
   console.log(id);
});
```

С недавних пор стало возможным к элементами добавлять произвольный data-атрибуты. Эту возможность нам предоставил HTML5. Убедитесь, что Ваш браузер поддерживает HTML5. Добавить к кнопке data-атрибут data-row-id со значением равным индексу строки. Этот атрибут извлекается в обработчике и автор вопроса может воспользоваться так полюбившейся ему функцией eq, не утруждая себя вычислением индекса строки.

Comment: CСпасибо конечно но у меня таких row будет ооколо 100 а может 200 сотен .Да и eq я люблю)СПасибо большоей за ваш Отзыв комент

Comment: Да хотя бы 100500. Ни что мешает записать какой-то атрибут.

Comment: ААААА я не так понел

Comment: Этот метод очень дажееее ничего !!!! Спасибооооо

Comment: Увыыы мой EE не поддерживает  data-row-index="3"

Comment: @Sergey .inputk что это?

Comment: Что-то твой код не совсем работает. А точнее совсем не

Comment: @elik Это же новаторский вариянт. data-* это из html 5. Видимо очень древний Ваш EE.

Comment: @L.Vadim в вопросе был '.inpuik`. В ответе опечатка.

Comment: @SLy_huh я и не стремился сделать рабочий вариант, а только показать направление. Было бы больше исходного кода в вопросе и ответах, чтобы можно было скопипастить заготовки, то возможно и заработало бы. И конечно же опечатки. Кому надо мысль уловит, уточнит у авторитетных источников и допилит как надо.